# How to add a new line on a script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I don't know if my title is helpful at all but here is my problem I want to make a type writer effect in JS, CSS, HTML, everything works fine apart from add a new line of text when I try added a new line it dose not show.

```js
 var str = "<p>I want to put text here then another line under this one</p>",
 <!--var str = "<p>text here</p>",--> <!--This is what I tried to do to add a new line-->
    i = 0,
    isTag,
    text;

(function type() {
    text = str.slice(0, ++i);
    if (text === str) return;
    
    document.getElementById('typewriter').innerHTML = text;

    var char = text.slice(-1);
    if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
    if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;

    if (isTag) return type();
    setTimeout(type, 80);
}());
```

```css
#typewriter {
  color: lime;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="typewriter"></div>
```

Comment: You can use `\n` or `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "My text\nSome more text";
var stra = str.split("");
var tw = document.getElementById("output");
function type(){
   var char = stra.shift();
   if (char){
       tw.innerHTML += char;
       setTimeout(type, 80);
   }
 
}
type();
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<br />`

```
var str = "<p>I want to put text here<br /> then another line under this one</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to group paragragh elements using [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) and add display style property of span to block.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var str = "<p><span>I want to put text here then another line under this one</span><span>text here</span></p>";

  (function type(isInTagArg, indexArg) {
    var index = indexArg || 0;
    if (index >= str.length)
      return;

    var isInTag = isInTagArg || false;
    if (isInTag == false) {
      if (str.charAt(index) == '<') {
        return type(true, index + 1);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('typewriter').innerHTML = str.substr(0, index + 1);
      }
    } else {
      if (str.charAt(index) == '>') {
        return type(false, index + 1);
      }
      return type(true, index + 1);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {type(false, index + 1)}, 80);
  }());
}
```

```css
#typewriter {
  color: lime;
  text-align: center;
}
#typewriter span
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="typewriter"></div>
```